# Meg sits in dark obsessing, reference?

Tags: reference, family-guy

In the Annie Award-winning Family Guy episode "Barely Legal", at one point Meg sits in the dark obsessing about Brian turning the light on and off. Is this a reference to something?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a parody of a scene from Fatal Attraction.

In Fatal Attraction, Glenn Close's character is obsessed with Michael Douglas's character, much like Meg is obsessed with Brian in this episode.

Clip here: